# Quote source: "How do you never run out of ideas? You remember those of your youth." - or similar

Tags: quote-source

I remember an English quote; it goes roughly like this: "How do you never run out of ideas? You remember those of your youth." - or similar... Who said this and where?

I think I read this sentence roughly a decade ago in an interview with Pierre Deligne or some other mathematician where it was included as a quote by somebody else; in the sense that Deligne or some other mathematician answered to a question by roughly saying: "Somebody once said that you never run out of ideas by remembering those of your youth."

I am pretty sure Deligne stressed on several occasions in interviews the importance of the influence of his ideas in his youth - what he then found "interesting", which he picked up later and elaborated on them, which nourished him a lifetime --- but I can't find an interview where the passage is directly included as I remember it, but just as a vague paraphrase.

For answers, I'm interested in references to interviews with Deligne or other mathematicians where such a passage is included as well to "somebody" who originally said this.

Comment: The request for "similar thoughts" is veering dangerously close to "list question" territory  - I'd say it's fallen into it. An unbounded set of possible answers (subject to debate on what is similar enough etc.) is not allowed on this site. Lists, if they are allowed at all, [must be restricted to some finite search space](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1561/11259)). Perhaps simply remove that line, and then ask in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1037/the-reading-room), where lists/recommendations are perfectly acceptable

Comment: You can remove the last sentence, if you prefer. I'm actually not interested in "similar" thoughts but what the mathematician was referring to. That might be hard to track without asking him - hence the broader question so that I can choose from possible answers and do further research...:)